# Why do STL function calls are done via PLT and not directly?

Tags: c++, linux, stl, libstdc++

I find it odd, that whole of STL is marked with visibility default and as a result is exported as weak symbols and calls to it go via PLT or GOT if compiled with `-no-flt`

In example below I'd expect STL functions to be no different than unexported `int t(int)` function, calls to which are direct.

```
#include <vector>

__attribute__((noinline))
int t(int i) {
    return i + 1;
}


__attribute__((visibility("default")))
std::size_t f(std::vector<int>& v, int i) {
    v.push_back(t(i));
    return v.size();
}
```

In disassembly, when compiled with `-Os -fpic -shared -fvisibility=hidden` we see calls are indirect:

```
    1206:  call   10e0 <void std::vector<...>::_M_realloc_insert<int>(...)@plt>
```

And symbol is marked as weak in `nm -C`:

```
0000000000001232 W void std::vector<...>::_M_realloc_insert<int>(...)
```

[Godbolt link](https://godbolt.org/z/3TjdfbzGd) with my test.

Comment: The standard library implementation resides in a shared library. How do you plan to use a shared library with no exported symbols?

Comment: My question is about STL functions, which are templates and their body is instantiated in my shared library, not in libstdc++

Comment: You compiled it as a shared library when you specified -fpic. The template instantiation is shared with all object files in your binary and the method of sharing you choose is -fpic so you get the PLT.

Comment: Function `int t(int)` is also shared with all object files, yet it is not going via PLT.

Comment: how do you know there isn't a `std::vector<int>::push_back` call elsewhere in `std`?

Comment: OK got it. See https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=36022